# How to convert SQL query to Power BI DAX query?

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax, rank, row-number

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8SqS.png)

Hi, i want to convert my sql query to a DAX measures for to filter all that have Rank 1 only. I've been trying to use RankX(Filter) but I get duplicate ranks. Thank you

**row_number() over (partition by date,customer, type order by day)**

```
 
┌──────────┬──────────┬─────┬──────┬──────────────┬
│ Day      │ Customer │ Day │ Type │ Desired Rank │
├──────────┼──────────┼─────┼──────┼──────────────
│ 6/1/2020 │ DDD      │   1 │ D    │            1 │
│ 6/1/2020 │ DDD      │   0 │ M    │            1 │
│ 6/1/2020 │ DDD      │   1 │ D    │            2 │
│ 6/1/2020 │ DDD      │   0 │ M    │            3 │
│ 6/1/2020 │ FFF      │   0 │ M    │            1 │
│ 6/1/2020 │ FFF      │   0 │ M    │            2 │
│ 6/1/2020 │ FFF      │   0 │ M    │            3 │
│ 6/1/2020 │ FFF      │   0 │ M    │            4 │
│ 6/1/2020 │ BBB      │   1 │ D    │            1 │
│ 6/1/2020 │ BBB      │   0 │ M    │            1 │
│ 6/1/2020 │ BBB      │ 0   │ M    │            2 │ 
│ 6/1/2020 │ BBB      │ 0   │ M    │            3 │
│ 6/2/2020 │ FFF      │ 2   │ D    │            1 │
│ 6/2/2020 │ BBB      │ 2   │ D    │            1 │
│ 6/3/2020 │ FFF      │ 3   │ D    │            1 │ 
│ 6/3/2020 │ FFF      │ 3   │ D    │            2 │
│ 6/3/2020 │ FFF      │ 3   │ D    │            3 │
│ 6/4/2020 │ DDD      │ 4   │ D    │            1 │
│ 6/4/2020 │ DDD      │ 4   │ D    │            2 │
│ 6/4/2020 │ DDD      │ 4   │ D    │            3 │
│ 6/4/2020 │ FFF      │ 4   │ D    │            1 │
│ 6/4/2020 │ FFF      │ 4   │ D    │            2 │
│ 6/5/2020 │ EEE      │ 5   │ D    │            1 │
│ 6/5/2020 │ EEE      │ 5   │ D    │            2 │
│ 6/5/2020 │ DDD      │ 5   │ D    │            1 │
│ 6/5/2020 │ DDD      │ 5   │ D    │            2 │
│ 6/5/2020 │ DDD      │ 5   │ D    │            3 │
│ 6/5/2020 │ FFF      │ 5   │ D    │            1 │
└─────────────────────┴─────┴──────┴──────────────┘
```

Comment: Please add more detail to your question. Have a read of this for some guidance. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Provide same data with expected output as a table here instead of image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this following steps to achieve your required output.

**Step-1:** Go to **Power Query Editor** and Add a index column to your table as shown in the below image. This is required as you have same value in multiple row for date,customer, type combination. I tried but found unexpected RANKX is generating for having same value in all rows for a group. For this reason Index column is created.

> ***Index column is created to keep different value in each row just. No other purpose is there for this column.***

[image]

**Step-2:** Get back to your report by clicking "Close & Apply" button.

**Step-3:** Now create a custom column in your table with this following code-

```
group_wise_rank = 

RANKX (
    FILTER (
        'your_table_name',
        'your_table_name'[Date] = EARLIER ('your_table_name'[Date])
            && 'your_table_name'[Customer] = EARLIER ('your_table_name'[Customer])
            && 'your_table_name'[Type] = EARLIER ('your_table_name'[Type])
    ),
    'your_table_name'[Index],
    ,
    ASC
)
```

This tricks should work for you.